# Is java binding included in opencv ubuntu package?

Tags: java, opencv

searching for opencv package with

```
apt-cache search opencv
```

i found

```
libcv2.4
```

and the pyton binding

```
python-opencv
```

Do you know about a java binding package?

Answer (score 0):

Your version of OpenCV doesn't have Java bindings, they are available from version 2.4.4 - Java bindings didn't used to be included by default in OpenCV, but it now supports Java bindings;  - [announcement](http://opencv.org/opencv-java-api.html).

[Get OpenCV with desktop Java support](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.4-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html)

Comment: Thanks, I've already built it from source and activated java binding but to do dthis I had to install a loto of development package.

Moreover I had to compile it on over 5 PC so I would find an elegant method to have java bindings on all machines.

Perhaps through offial packages. :)